# How to Convert TypeScript ES6 into ES5 using Babel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am building a component library and would like to be able to use this in other places.

I have the following component at `src/components/List/List.tsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from '@mui/material/styles/styled'

import MuiList, { ListProps as MuiListProps } from '@mui/material/List'

const ListStyled = styled(MuiList)`
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
`

export const List: React.FC<MuiListProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <ListStyled {...props}>{children}</ListStyled>
}

export default List
```

When running:

```
rm -rf dist && NODE_ENV=production babel src/components --out-dir dist --copy-files --ignore __tests__,__snapshots__,__mocks__,test.tsx,stories.js
```

The compiled version is as `dist/List/List.tsx`:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from '@mui/material/styles/styled'

import MuiList, { ListProps as MuiListProps } from '@mui/material/List'

const ListStyled = styled(MuiList)`
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
`

export const List: React.FC<MuiListProps> = ({ children, ...props }) => {
  return <ListStyled {...props}>{children}</ListStyled>
}

export default List
```

The file is identical. I would like to see `dist/List/List.js` ideally for my packages to use. But I realize, maybe with TS it cannot work this way, as the interfaces, etc will not be used anymore? So logically I believe I would need `dist/List/List.js` accompanied with `dist/List/List.d.ts`? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that babel does not recognize `.tsx` file extensions by default. The `--copy-files` flag copies files that are not compiled - this is currently why your file is being copied.

You can add an extensions flag with `.tsx` included `--extensions '.tsx'` and it will attempt to compile them.

I was able to compile your file using `babel src/components/List.tsx --out-dir dist --extensions '.tsx' --presets @babel/preset-typescript`

Example output:

```
"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
  value: true
});
exports.default = exports.List = void 0;

var _react = _interopRequireDefault(require("react"));

var _styled = _interopRequireDefault(require("@mui/material/styles/styled"));

var _List = _interopRequireDefault(require("@mui/material/List"));

var _excluded = ["children"];

var _templateObject;

function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }

function _objectWithoutProperties(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded); var key, i; if (Object.getOwnPropertySymbols) { var sourceSymbolKeys = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(source); for (i = 0; i < sourceSymbolKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceSymbolKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; if (!Object.prototype.propertyIsEnumerable.call(source, key)) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } } return target; }

function _objectWithoutPropertiesLoose(source, excluded) { if (source == null) return {}; var target = {}; var sourceKeys = Object.keys(source); var key, i; for (i = 0; i < sourceKeys.length; i++) { key = sourceKeys[i]; if (excluded.indexOf(key) >= 0) continue; target[key] = source[key]; } return target; }

function _taggedTemplateLiteral(strings, raw) { if (!raw) { raw = strings.slice(0); } return Object.freeze(Object.defineProperties(strings, { raw: { value: Object.freeze(raw) } })); }

var ListStyled = (0, _styled.default)(_List.default)(_templateObject || (_templateObject = _taggedTemplateLiteral(["\n  text-decoration: none;\n  cursor: pointer;\n"])));

var List = function List(_ref) {
  var children = _ref.children,
      props = _objectWithoutProperties(_ref, _excluded);

  return <ListStyled {...props}>{children}</ListStyled>;
};

exports.List = List;
var _default = List;
exports.default = _default;
```

Comment: Brilliant thank you JDK. Would you happen to know how to get the typescript definitions to complain along with this too? for example: `dist/List/List.d.ts`

Comment: @JamieHutber this depends on your tsc/babel setup - see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/babel-with-typescript.html

Comment: Another question from me. It seems that this type of exported file cannot be used without the babel preset: `"@babel/preset-react"` it is possible to have them exported and useable without this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for creating a library or a package for your project you should use [`rollup`](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/) alongside implementing the `typescript` [configurations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rollup/plugin-typescript).

I experienced it and lost many hours to configure the base but totally my friend nominated **[`TSDX`](https://tsdx.io/)**, Zero-config CLI for TypeScript package development, which contains:

1. CJS
2. ESM
3. UMD
4. Treeshaking
5. Live Playground
6. Dev/Prod Builds
7. Zero-config
8. Project Templates
9. TypeScript
10. Rollup
11. Jest
12. Prettier
13. ESLint

It's created by [Jared Palmer](https://github.com/jaredpalmer), this TSDX package is and CLI for creating what you want, even you can add your extra configurations. it has complete documentations too and a very active community. All the configs of TypeScript, Babel, building are fully configured in the best optimum case.

You can create a new package by this command:

```
npx tsdx create [your lib name]
```

And then move your codes into `src` folder, even the exporting types doesn't need any configs, just export the types in the root export file of `src` folder like below:

```js
// index.ts or index.tsx // the root index file in src folder
import type { OneComponentProps } from '../OneComponent';

export type { OneComponentProps };
```